# Getting wrong number or types of arguments in call to exception while executing stored procedure

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have created below stored procedure in oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "UPDATE_ASSET_LOB_PROC"(
asset_id IN integer,
distribution_id_list IN distribution_id)

IS
CURSOR dist_id
IS
select adt.lkp_dist_type from Asset_Dist_Type adt where adt.asset_id= asset_id;

BEGIN

  delete  from Asset_Dist_Type where asset_id= asset_id;
  commit;
  for i IN dist_id 
  LOOP
  insert into Asset_Dist_Type values (asset_id_list,i.lkp_dist_type);
  commit;
  END LOOP;

END UPDATE_ASSET_LOB_PROC;
```

distribution_is a custom type. I have created it as

```
`CREATE TYPE distribution_id AS TABLE OF NUMBER;`
```

My java code is as follows.

```
Integer[] idArray = new Integer[selectedDistributionTypes.size()]; 
        idArray = selectedDistributionTypes.toArray(idArray); 

    entityManager.createNativeQuery("CALL UPDATE_ASSET_LOB_PROC (:assetIdParam,:distributionIdParam)")
                    .setParameter("assetIdParam", assetId).setParameter("distributionIdParam", idArray).executeUpdate();
```

I am getting

```
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPDATE_ASSET_LOB_PROC'`.
```

What is the wrong thing here? I guess it is with stored procedure. But I am not much into writing stored procedure. OR is it feasible to pass a comma separated list and split it in stored procedure?

Comment: please show us the java code which is calling your procedure

Comment: @StefanBeike. I have updated the code in question.

Comment: It most probably the `.setParameter("distributionIdParam", idArray)` is not setting your Type as it should. Then the database is receiving something that it can't handle.

Comment: @JorgeCampos.. Hi. idArray is an array of inetegers. And it should set value to distribution_id_list. It is of type TABLE OF NUMBER. Should I change anything here? Or is there any other way to send an array to stored procedure?

Comment: I have worked a lot with StoredProcedures and I runs into problems when I have a different naming. That is here also the case: asset_id(SQL) = assetIdParam(Java) and also for distribution_id_list = distributionIdParam

Take the same name in Java and SQL

Comment: @StefanBeike. I changed the variable name in stored procedure. but getting same exception.

Comment: And one more doubt. I have implemented the requirement with HQL. But my lead wants me to do it in stored procedure. Does stored procedure takes less time to update DB compared to HQL while updating multiple records at a time?

Comment: @StefanBeike At first glance, it looks like a parameter name mismatch. But since the Java code doesn't use named parameters (it uses "UPDATE_ASSET_LOB_PROC (:assetIdParam, ..." instead of "UPDATE_ASSET_LOB_PROC (asset_ID => :assetIdParam, ...", it should be ok.

Comment: @Sanjay Please add the Java code where you create + set the idArray Parameter.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt. I have a arraylist in which I get id's from the front end. I am convertring that arraylist into an array i.e., idArray. I have updated the code in question now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution to this problem. I removed the created custom type "distribution id" and made distribution_id_list  as varchar2. From bean, I sent a comma separated list and in stored procedure, removed the comma's looping over it as below.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (distribution_id_list, '[^,]+', 1,LEVEL) dist_id
                             FROM DUAL
                             CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (distribution_id_list, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

Inside a for loop I can use dist_id to whatever the operation I want.